# How to deal with HTML error codes and timeout from HttpClient()

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `HttpClient` to connect to a server (see simplified code below). I cant figure out how I would respond to HTML error codes (e.g. `403`) and timeouts so I can report what the result is.

When I encounter a `403` error code an error pop-up occurs in Visual Studio. But I can figure out how I convert this into `try` in the code. i.e. is the name of the exception present in the error pop-up?

```
using System.Net.Http;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.PostAsync(dutMacUrl, null).Result;
var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

Comment: why not using async?

Comment: Dont know what you mean. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) feature to simplify your code and avoid using `Result`.

for example

```
public async Task<string> Foo(string uri)
{
    var client = new HttpClient();
    try
    {
        var response = await client.PostAsync(uri, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //here you handle exceptions
    }

    // use this if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) { do what you want }
    // or this if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) { do what you want }
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks - I see where you are getting the status code (which I guess is related to the HTML response code i was talking about)  but is there a way to deal with timeout as well?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webAPI another option is to use `IHttpActionResult`

```
public object IHttpActionResult mymethod()
{
    // instantiate your class or object
    IEnumerable<yourClass> myobject = new IEnumerable<yourClass>();         
    // assuming you want to return a collection
    try
    {
        // do stuff
        // handle dto or map result back to object 
        return Ok(myobject)
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        // return a bad request if the action fails
        return BadRequest(e.Message)
    }
}
```

This would allow you to make a call to your api endpoint and either return a successful response with the updated object or return a bad request if the endpoint fails.